# Control Click only working when the cursor is hovering over the specified window

Tags: click

I am very new at coding (I am mainly just doing tutorials etc. to help me farm on different games).

For this specific question, it is for control click. I have a triple monitor setup. My main objective is to have an auto clicker happen on my Wizard101 client that happens while I am doing other things on my computer, allowing me to click and focus on other tabs and type while it runs in the background.

After looking through lots of posts and youtube tutorials, my current script/code looks as follows:

```
#SingleInstance, Force
#NoEnv
SendMode Input
fire := 0

NumpadDiv::SetTimer, AutoFire, % (fire := !fire) ? "1000" : "Off"

AutoFire:
ControlClick, x948 y534, ahk_class Wizard Graphical Client,,, pos
 return
```

Unfortunately, this is basically just working as a regular auto clicker, not one that can be used in the background. My cursor must be hovering over the window for it to click. I have the coordinates in there, I have it set as pos at the end, I am very confused to what to fix this.

Any and all fixes/help are greatly appreciated :)

Comment: What language is the script in your question?